# Cropping an image from the center into the largest square you can make in Yii2 Imagine?

Tags: php, yii2, imagick, php-imagine, gmagick

I'm using the Yii2 extension [Imagine](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-imagine-image.html) and I need to make `150x150` images from user uploads.

Currently I am just doing something like this:

```
use yii\imagine\Image;

....

Image::thumbnail($save_path, $img_size, $img_size)->save($save_path);
```

Obviously this can cause issues if one of the dimensions is < `150px` once resized.

So what I'm trying to primarily figure out is how to crop the image into a **square** *before* it is resized, so that when I resize it there won't be any *aspect ratio* issues.

Now, I know you can crop the image with something like:

```
Image::crop($save_path, $img_size, $img_size, [5, 5]);
```

But problem is doing this *before* resizing the image will likely not give you what you want since the image may be so large and cropping it *after* resizing won't work either as one dimension may already have been reduced to < `150px`.

So what I'm trying to work out is how can I crop the image *before* resizing to the **maximum** size square possible *and* from the center out?

**Edit:**

Ok, I have worked out a way to handle this, but was wondering if there was anyway to accomplish the below easily or will I need to code it myself?

- Work out the smallest dimension (width or height)
- Then take that dimension and that will be the largest square you can have
- Work out how to position that in the center for the crop
- Now you can do the resize
- If after the resize either side is smaller than 150, create new white background image and then center the new image on that
- Save image
- Done!

Comment: if you can not accomplish it with `imagine/Image` try other extension like `Gd\Imagine`

Comment: maybe it can help you https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/API/Imagine/Image/Box.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another try :p

```
<?php

use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\Point;

// ...

$thumbnail = Image::thumbnail($save_path, $img_size, $img_size);
$size = $thumbnail->getSize();
if ($size->getWidth() < $img_size or $size->getHeight() < $img_size) {
    $white = Image::getImagine()->create(new Box($img_size, $img_size));
    $thumbnail = $white->paste($thumbnail, new Point($img_size / 2 - $size->getWidth() / 2, $img_size / 2 - $size->getHeight() / 2));
}
$thumbnail->save($save_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the fourth parameter of Image::thumbnail()?

```
Image::thumbnail($save_path, $img_size, $img_size, Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)->save($save_path);
```

From http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-imagine-baseimage.html#thumbnail()-detail:

> If thumbnail mode is ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET, the original
>   image is scaled down so it is fully contained within the thumbnail
>   dimensions. The rest is filled with background that could be
>   configured via yii\imagine\Image::$thumbnailBackgroundColor and
>   yii\imagine\Image::$thumbnailBackgroundAlpha.

Comment: I will check this out and let you know :) I may have overlooked this option.

Comment: _Almost_ did what I wanted; it just doesn't place images _smaller_ than the thumb size within a filled background; they just come out the original size.

Comment: Actually testing it more it's not what I'm looking for as it reduces the image to get the _whole_image into the thumb, rather than making the largest square it can from the center. Thanks though.